# Calculating time with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, time

I created one start to log a "start time" and save into a plist file, and a an other script to read the start time and calculate the number of time elapsed from the start time and now (reading time)

first script (log time in plist) :

```
set myDate to date string of (current date)
set [dayLetter, dayNumber, MonthLetter, yearNumber] to the words of myDate
set t to (time string of (current date))
set [hoursInNumber, minutesInNumber, secondInNumber] to the words of t


set startTimeValue to (current date)
set startTimeClear to dayLetter & " " & dayNumber & " " & MonthLetter & " at " & hoursInNumber & ":" & minutesInNumber

set plistR to {startTime:startTimeValue, startTimeClear:startTimeClear}
tell application "System Events"
    set plistf to make new property list file ¬
        with properties {name:"~/Desktop/myTime.plist"}
    set plistf's value to plistR
end tell
```

second script (read plist)

```
set NowTimeValue to (current date)
set the plistfile_path to "~/Desktop/myTime.plist"
tell application "System Events"
    set p_list to property list file (plistfile_path)
    -- read the plist data
    set startTimeValue to value of property list item "startTime" of p_list
end tell
set Elapsed to startTimeValue - NowTimeValue
```

the main issue is, the time given is in second, and if I try yo divid by 60 that give me an hour.

how can I get this time in minutes / hours instead?

Answer (score 2):

Never-mind find the solution :

```
set Elapsed to (startTimeValue - NowTimeValue as number) / 60
```

Comment: although how can I only keep two decimal?

Comment: `set x to (round (x * 100)) / 100`

Comment: @CJK, RE: "set x to (round (x * 100)) / 100" --  That just returns: error "The variable x is not defined." number -2753 from "x" 

Comment: @CJK, I hope you know I'm just joking around with that previous comment. 

Comment: @user3439894 I wouldn't have known if you hadn't it was ironic, so I'm glad you did.  It retuned the voice in my head that was judging you for being an idiot to now laughing because I am the idiot.  +1 for the invoking of humility and my smile on an otherwise rainy, cold and chaotic day.